# Как работают эксплойты?

Tags: python-3.x, безопасность

Всем привет,можете объяснить как работают эксплойты,я знаю то что не которые переполняют буфер типа

`buff = 'A'*50`
или я встречаю где используют  шестнадцатеричную систему я так понимаю это блоки памяти (я могу ошибаться)
`buff = '/0x41'*50`
Ну я понял то что `/0x41` это символ `А`
так вот нахожу такие эксплойты там я код вообще не понимаю

[https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/44713/](http://%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

как работает

Comment: Ну, если хотите знать, садитесь поудобней: шаг-1: сначала берут софт, и делают фаззинг. шаг-2: когда фаззинг проведен - анализируют данные. шаг 3: пишут эксплойт. Это вкратце.

Answer (score 4):

В целом, эксплойт это не какой-то волшебный набор символов, чтобы всё "взломать".

Эксплойт - это эксплуатация недостатков ПО с целью обхода защиты ПО. Чтобы понять что такое эксплойт, нужно понять как они создаются, а так-же обладать некоторыми знаниями в сфере информационной безопасности и стека технологий, которые использует цель.

Первым делом специалист по информационной безопасности проводит разведку цели. В ходе разведки, он выявляет технологии и вообще всю возможную информацию про цель.

```
Стоит отметить, что даже просто разведка цели, на которую у вас нет права 
(письменного!! договора с владельцем) - это уже нарушение закона почти во 
всех странах и преследуется уголовно. Даже просто запрос на целевой сервер 
засветит ваш ip и кучу служебных данных по которым вас очень быстро найдут. 
Даже VPN и Proxy вам не помогут. Так что даже пробовать не стоит.
```

Вторым шагом специалист анализирует исходный код (если проект open-source) и выявляет недостатки и исследует на что они влияют.

В случае с закрытым исходным кодом прибегают к фаззингу или декомпиляции.

Третим шагом специалист автоматизирует шаги для эксплуатации недостатков на удобном ему ЯП. В вашем случае, на Phyton.

Стоит заметить, что эксплойт обычно не даёт "взломать" систему напрямую, но может использоваться в комплексе с другими эксплойтами.

По ссылке, приведенной вами скрипт, генерирует специальный текстовый файл `Evil.txt` а вставка его содержимого в поле "пароль" в программе FTPShell Server версии 6.80 приводит к переполнению буффера и похоже к выполнению произвольного кода (payload). А в peyload, похоже, загружен примитивный скомпилированный калькулятор для демонстрации.